# How to fix the missing Develop Branch in remote in Sourcetree?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I have cloned an existing repository and find that only master branch is found in remote but develop branch is not there. When I tried to merge master and /origin/master branch to local develop branch, below errors pop up. How can I fix the error and create the /origin/develop branch? Thanks

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks push -v --tags --set-upstream origin develop:develop
Pushing to 'GOT folder'
error: refs/heads/develop does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/feature/xxxx does not point to a valid object!
remote: error: refs/heads/develop does not point to a valid object!        
remote: error: refs/heads/feature/xxxx does not point to a valid object!        
remote: fatal: bad object .alternate        
error: refs/heads/develop does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/feature/xxxxx does not point to a valid object!
fatal: bad object .alternate
To 'GOT folder'
 = [up to date]      1.0 -> 1.0
 = [up to date]      1.1 -> 1.1
 = [up to date]      1.2 -> 1.2
 ! [remote rejected] develop -> develop (missing necessary objects)
error: failed to push some refs to ''GIT folder''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned the develop branch in not on remote.

- So first create the `develop` branch on your local repo using

  `git checkout -b develop`
- Then pull branch `master` into this checked out develop branch by using

  `git pull origin master`
- Finally push your local develop branch to remote

  `git push origin HEAD`

Comment: When I run 'git push origin HEAD' , these 2 errors still pop up. Indeed origin/develop existed before, but I have no idea why today it was gone.
"remote: error: refs/heads/develop does not point to a valid object!        
remote: error: refs/heads/feature/xxxx does not point to a valid object!"

Comment: This might be happening because the upstream doesn't have the develop reference anymore. Could you try running `git remote prune origin --dry-run` and check the output. If everything looks good then you can run the prune command without dry-run option.